# Resuming a nohup terminal session

Tags: linux, terminal, nohup

How does one resume control of, or otherwise exchange information with, a terminal session that has been closed and is still running a process backgrounded using 'nohup'?

Answer (score 0):

Know the process ID of that `nohup` command and use this,

```
kill -CONT <PID>
```

It will resume the process of a background process.